# Displaying the row based on parameter selection in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: ssrs-2008

﻿﻿Hi ,

i got one requirement like

my report contains one parameter to select the values from the list box  , based on parameter selection the value needs to display in Report .

my requirement is when i select "Select All" check box from parameter then only total value should display at the end of the report i.e if user select other than "Select All"  check box option then report should not display total value row at the end of the report.

how do i fix this issue .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the parameter populated from a Dataset in the report?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your parameter is derived from a Dataset, you can use something like this for the **Hidden** property expression of the different rows in the Tablix:

```
=IIf(Count(Fields!ParameterDetail.Value, "ParameterDataset") = Parameters!MyParameter.Count
    , True
    , False)
```

You can change the `True` and `False` around depending on whether it's a detail or total row.

This is just comparing the number of selected parameter values `Parameters!MyParameter.Count` to the amount of available values to be selected `Count(Fields!ParameterDetail.Value, "ParameterDataset")` - if the values are equal, all available values must have been selected.

**Edit after comment**

As above, you need to set the **Row Visibility** property for rows you want to show/hide, using an expression that compares the items selected in the parameter to the total available.

I have a parameter as previously described:

[image]

The parameter is populated by the Dataset.

A simple tablix with a detail and total row:

[image]

To show/hide a row based on parameter selection set the **Row Visibility** to the expression above:

[image]

[image]

Detail row:

[image]

Total row:

[image]

Now, depending on how many parameter items are selected, the different rows will be shown/hidden.

Some items selected, only detail rows show:

[image]

All items selected, only total row shows:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply ,my requirement is i am displaying sum(fields!sal.value) at the end of the report. if you "select all" check box from  departments from parameter then only the total row should display the data in report other wise this report should not display total at the end i.e this row should hide from the report. please suggest how do i reach this requirement.

Comment: Added more details showing my answer working as required; please see above.

Comment: @Prasad, I added more details as requested, do you have any feedback?